# Why is a here-string command substitution considered as a single line?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, quoting, command-substitution

I'm experimenting with [`while read` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/240613) and there is a thing I don't understand.

The most basic scenario which reproduces the problem is the following: a bash script `a.sh` calls another script `b.sh` and displays the lines echoed by it:

> **`a.sh`**
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> while read line; do
>     echo "<<$line>>"
> done <<< `./b.sh`
> ```

> **`b.sh`**
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> echo "Hello"
> echo "World"
> ```

Running `b.sh` gives as expected:

```
Hello
World
```

On the other hand, when I run `a.sh`, the output is:

```
<<Hello World>>
```

while I expect it to be:

```
<<Hello>>
<<World>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting `""` quotes around ``"`./b.sh`"`` and see what happens.

Comment: You don't need `a.sh` to be surprised, just run `echo \`./b.sh\``. Then try `IFS=' '; echo \`./b.sh\``

Comment: @jw013: hm, interesting, it works. Doing `./b.sh | while read ... done` works too. Would you like writing an answer, explaining why the code in my question doesn't work, while two other alternatives do?

Comment: @jimmij: well, the example in my question is simplistic. Actually, what I need to do is to process the output, line by line, instead of simply echoing it.

Comment: @MainMa The main point is that whitespace inside expansions gets lost if you don't double-quote the expansion. You may want to read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. The `./b.sh | ...` example does not use any expansions so doesn't have the quoting problem. I could have sworn there was already a question like this but I can't find one at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Bash changelog between 4.4-alpha and 4.4-beta](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-08/msg00123.html):

> [...]
>
> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.4-beta, and
>   the previous version, bash-4.4-alpha.
>
> [...]
>
> z.  **Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation
>       has always said.**

That reads a bit ambiguously to me, but whatever changes was committed to the `bash` sources around that time had the effect that in Bash 4.4, the command

```
while read line; do
    printf '<<%s>>\n' "$line"
done <<< $( printf '%s\n' hello world )
```

will produce

```
<<hello>>
<<world>>
```

not

```
<<hello world>>
```

as in Bash 4.3.