# sed with here-string fails, but succeeds when echo output piped to sed

Tags: sed, find, echo, here-string

After updating `sed` to `4.4` version, `sed` doesn't replace spaces with commas in the output of `find` command given to it as `here-string`:

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4

ls -l /tmp/test/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  9 17:25 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  9 17:25 b

# NOT EXPECTED
sed "s: :,:g" <<< $(find /tmp/test/ -type f)
/tmp/test/b
/tmp/test/a
```

There are no issue in `sed` 4.2

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

ls -l /tmp/test/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  9 17:25 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  9 17:25 b

# as expected
sed "s: :,:g" <<< $(find /tmp/test/ -type f)
/tmp/test/a,/tmp/test/b
```

As a workaround, storing the result in variable and using `echo` helps:

```
a=$(find /tmp/test/ -type f)
echo $a | sed "s: :,:g" 
/tmp/test/b,/tmp/test/a
```

How to achieve the same output in `sed` 4.4 using `here-string` ?

**Update**

version of bash changed as well between the two systems:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20
```

old version

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48
```

Comment: Change `echo $a` to `echo "$a"`. Any difference?

Comment: The behavior is likely due to the version of the (bash?) shell that you are using, rather than the version of sed - see for example [Split string using IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397205/split-string-using-ifs/397208#397208)

Comment: This looks more like a change in shell quoting/parsing. Has the version of your shell also changed between the two systems?

Comment: FWIW best practice in this scenario would more usually be `find ... | sed ...`

Comment: @roaima yes. `echo "$a" | sed "s: :,:g"`  behaves like `sed`

Comment: @roaima yes, shell version changed as well, i've updated my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a here-string command substitution considered as a single line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164110/why-is-a-here-string-command-substitution-considered-as-a-single-line)

Comment: @they how is this a duplicate? It's a change in behaviour (bug fix) in bash

Comment: @roaima You are correct. If the question had been "why does this happen?", then it would have been a dupe, but now they ask "how can I work around it?", which makes it different.  I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [change](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES) between `bash` versions 4.3 and 4.4

> Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation has always said.

The correct behaviour is your new version as you were relying on a bug with your old code.

This will give you a comma-separated list of files,

```
find -type f | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

However, seeing as filenames themselves can contain newlines and commas, it's all too easy to break this kind of fragile code. If you care to share your processing - in a new question - I'm sure someone will recommend a better way of processing the file names reliably and safely.